# javascript / jquery: Get the changed content of textarea

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, forms, textarea

I'm new to javascript & jquery. i have a **textarea** with a preset content. If i change the value on the site by entering "new" and press the "showme" button the alert box **does show me the preset value**, **not the new contend** of the textarea.

Why is this? What i have to change to get the new content from my chrome browser?

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.4.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

    <form action="javascript:Output()">
    <textarea id='area1'>preset</textarea>
    <input type="submit" value="showme">
    </form>  

    <script>
    function Output() {
 var s = $('#area1').html();
    alert(s);
    }
    </script>
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to use [`val`](http://api.jquery.com/val/) method

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.4.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<form onsubmit="Output()">
  <textarea id='area1'>preset</textarea>
  <input type="submit" value="showme">
</form>  

<script>
  function Output() {
    var s = $('#area1').val();
    alert(s);
  }
</script>
```